# windows tile onclick animation on android

Tags: android, android-animation, staggered-gridview

I am using staggered `gridview` from etsy library to arrange my icons like in windows tile. Now I would like to have some animations similar to the one on windows mobile (when you click on an icon in your windows homescreen, the icon tiles tend to fly and disappear in 3D).
*Can someone help me out to create such an animation in android ?*

Comment: This like flip animation?\

Comment: Yeah i suppose its kinda flip like animation but it flies around in 3D ... Probably if you tap on any icon on the homescreen of a windows phone, the whole window transition is what i am keen to make it for my android app

Comment: Check this code: https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/